# rotate object inverse of camera positon x y

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a c# script to have the ball and arrow point the direction the player is standing(camera)(not looking, actual position), I've attached an image of what I am trying to attempt, I've tried a few things but I'm pretty much at square one. Thank you.
[image]

I have made the arrow a child of the ball, when I rotate the Y rotation of the ball, the arrow moves accordingly, but I do not know how to translate the values of my camera to the value of my ball y.

Comment: Please post what you tried, as this sounds like this should be pretty simple

Comment: Make sure that the arrow points in the ball's `forward` direction. then, `ball.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(ball.transform.position - player.transform.position);`

Comment: @BugFinder I have made the arrow a child of the ball, when I rotate the Y rotation of the ball, the arrow moves accordingly, but I do not know how to translate the values of my camera to the value of my ball y

Comment: @Ruzihm thank you, you are correct. How would I get the inverse of it because it currently points to me, not the opposite of me.

Comment: @MaxwellJones Thanks, I just realized I made that mistake. See the most recent edit. Might need to refresh the page.

Comment: backwards is the - of fowrards so instead of vector3.foward you can do -vector3.forward and it will be behind

Comment: @Ruzihm the arrow is rotating beneath the ground https://imgur.com/a/g5niUwm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the arrow's rotation being completely based on the ball, make an empty child of the ball, call it "arrow arm", then make the arrow  a child of the arrow arm:

```
ball
├── arrow arm
│   └── arrow
```

Make sure that the arrow points in the arrow arm's forward direction.

Then, find the position of the ball and the player but set at the same height. Then, set the rotation of the arrow Arm using [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to calculate the rotation that corresponds to the desired look direction:

```
Vector3 floorBallPos = ball.transform.position;
floorBallPos.y = 0f;

Vector3 floorPlayerPos = player.transform.position;
floorPlayerPos.y = 0f;

arrowArm.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(floorBallPos - floorPlayerPos);
```

Run this code on every frame that the arrow needs to be rendered, including ones while the ball is rolling, if you want the arrow to be rendered.

Comment: Thank you guys it's almost correct, I am having a problem with the rotation of the arrow as its pointing up and down. here is the image https://imgur.com/a/g5niUwm

Comment: because you havent allowed for a difference in Y.. there for if arrow is at 2 and ball at 0 its going to look "down" to the ball.

Comment: dont freeze the Y, change it

Comment: Thank you, perfect

Comment: @BugFinder how do i keep the arrow always directly infront of the arrow after moving the ball, it seems to be pointing the right way though. https://imgur.com/a/L2Q9JV1

Comment: how do you keep the arrow in front of the arrow? that makes no sense

Comment: @BugFinder my bad, arrow in front of ball. Its been a long day lol, always pointing forwards

Comment: if the arrow is fixed, they just have it as a child of the ball...... so it points forwards and is however far away and it will stay there.

Comment: @MaxwellJones That doesn't show enough info. put a tiny Sphere where the camera is so we can see it and show the [local translation gizmo](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/TransformExample2.png) of the ball. I'm guessing you are setting the global rotation or position of the arrow at some point, or something else that would change its local rotation or position. As long as the arrow's local position and rotation don't change, this shouldn't be occurring.

Comment: @Ruzihm yes it is a child and fixed to be a distance away from the ball but when the ball moves the arrow rotates around 360 but stays the same distance away

Comment: @MaxwellJones Well, that doesn't show the information that would help, but I can infer that you didn't call the code in this answer the frames these were rendered. I edited my answer to account for that. Note that it does not change the ball's rotation anymore. And you should now call it on every frame where the arrow needs to be rendered.

Comment: @Ruzihm should the script be attached to the ball or the arrow or arrow arm

Comment: @MaxwellJones It doesn't really matter, since all of the transforms are qualified by the `ball`, `player`, and `arrowArm` fields. If you attach it to the arrow arm, you can use `transform.rotation = ...` instead of `arrowArm.transform.rotation = ...` which you might find easier to read.

Comment: @Ruzihm thank you for your help but that did not work, now the arrow is rotating around https://imgur.com/a/tA1CRG1

Comment: @Ruzihm I solved that problem, it was because the arrow had a regidbody, but now my ball isnt rotating to the direction i want, just the arrow

Comment: Glad I could help. Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).